# Regex for Phone Numbers in Automate the boring stuff with python

Tags: python

what does this code mean? `(\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))`? I understand that (\d{3}) means that the digit is repeated 3 times, but I don't understand the rest of it. Can someone please explain

Comment: hopefully this can help [regex python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: You can also use [this website](https://regex101.com/), for testing and getting details about your regex

Comment: Note that you should always format code as code with the editor on SO. Here, failing to do so makes the `\` before the parentheses disappear, which changes completely the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```py
"(\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))"
```

What an eye-**`capturing`** regex hm?

---

Let's do this one by one.

`\d{3}` means "match any number that occurs three times."

`\( or \)` means "match the literal parenthesis, but this has no special meaning at all."

`|` means "match the previous statement OR the next statement."

`( with )` means "match the regex inside me and capture/remember them."

---

## TL;DR

Match a 3-digit number or a 3-digit number inside parentheses and capture/remeber the match.